# Splitting an array of objects based on unique combinations of two properties

Tags: arrays, vue.js, ecmascript-6

For my time-tracking app, I'm storing time entries in an array of objects each looking like this:

```
{
  date: "20181206",
  hours: "4",
  projectId: "65WchP9X46HlOYUzmWrL",
  taskId: "fJTU7wggJHbg1uRuRUdHjS5mn8J3"
}
```

I need to group, into separate arrays, all objects by unique combinations of `ProjectId` - `TaskId` properties, so that each resulting array gets all entries for one particular project and one particular task (an array for `project #1` / `task #1`, another for `project #1` / `task #2`, another for `project #2` / `task #1`, etc).

I know how to do that with one property, but is there a simple way to achieve the same with two properties?

Note: my global array is initially populated like so:

```
weekTimes = [];
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  weekTimes.push(doc.data());
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a composite key from `projectId` and `taskId`:

```js
grouped = {}

for (weekTime of weekTimes) {
  var key = `${weekTime.projectId}/${weekTime.taskId}`

  if (grouped[key] === undefined) {
    // if the key doesn't exist, weekTime is the first item, create the key 
    // and assign an array with the first item to it
    grouped[key] = [ weekTime ]
  } else {
    // if the key already exists in grouped, just push new item to that key
    grouped[key].push(weekTime)
  }
}

// if you don't need the keys
Object.values(grouped)
```

Or use `lodash` `groupby`:

```
const _ = require('lodash')

_.groupBy(weekTimes, x => x.projectId + '/' + x.taskId)
```

Comment: Thanks! However, each array inside `grouped` contains all entries for a given project regardless of `taskId`, whereas I want an array for every different combination of `projectId` / `taskId`: an array for p1/t1, another for p1/t2, another for p1/t3 and of course another for p2/tx. Right now, I get a single array containing all entries for p1/t1, p1/t2/ p1/t3...

Comment: That should be how this is working. I can't really tell without looking at your code. Maybe you can post a reproducible example?

Comment: Actually your code works perfectly, there was a flaw in my implementation of it. Thanks! I don't really understand it though, is there a way you could edit and explain a little? Especially the `grouped[key].push(weekTime)` and `grouped[key] = [ weekTime ]` parts if you don't mind. Thanks!

Comment: Explanation added. Also reordered the logic to make it a little clearer.